# what is wrong with this programme on java

Tags: java, eclipse

This is code for asking the user for input. These errors are coming -

```
MyFirstJavaProgram.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
          ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class MyFirstJavaProgram
MyFirstJavaProgram.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
          Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
                         ^
  symbol:   class Scanner
  location: class MyFirstJavaProgram
2 errors
```

Kindly explain to me these errors

```
int a;
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter a number");
a=in.nextInt();
double b=200;
double c=a+b;
System.out.println("sum is"+c);
```

Comment: import Scanner class

Comment: If you´re using eclipse, it should tell you what´s wrong and even give you hints how to solve the problem, in this specific case it could even include the import.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

at top (beneath package decalaration) of your source file is missing

Answer (score 0):

At the top between the `package` and the `class` put
`import java.util.Scanner;`